# How to create a serial over LAN server under Linux, using virtual ports

Tags: linux, serial-port, netcat

I am able to connect to serial over LAN devices (like USRIOT-TCP-232-302), as client, from my linux server, using `socat` and it works pretty well.

I now would like to have devices connecting to the server (devices can be switched from server connection type to client connection type).

I also need the connection to be on virtual ports, not on existing (physical) serial ports.

I did read about `ser2net` an `netcat` (`nc`) but I have been unable to make them working.

Does anyone have a **WORKING** example on how to implement **serial over LAN server** under **Linux**, with **virtual ports**?